# How to filter a dataframe with a list of start and end date

Tags: python, pandas

How do I filter out rows from dataframe with start dates and end dates from another df, and combine all rows into 1 df?

DF to be filtered

```
                 date                  x                 
0             2021-01-20              10    ...          
1             2021-01-22              20    ...        
2             2021-01-24              30    ...      
3             2021-03-22              4     ...          
4             2021-03-25              4     ...    
5             2021-03-27              4     ...
```

time filter dataframe

```
                start_date          end_date               
0             2021-12-30            2021-01-23        
1             2021-03-23            2021-04-01                
2               ....                   ....
3               ....                   ....
```

Expected result dataframe

```
            filter_date                 x            
0             2021-01-20              10    ...          
1             2021-01-22              20    ...        
4             2021-03-25              4     ...    
5             2021-03-27              4     ...
```

Thank you!

Comment: A row in your input reaches the output if the date is between any pair of start-end dates?

Comment: solved with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66019099/pandas-filter-dataframe-by-another-dataframe-of-time-intervals

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get all days between start and end dates and then filter by [`Series.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) in [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
print (df2)
   start_date    end_date
0  2020-12-30  2021-01-23
1  2021-03-23  2021-04-01

L = [x for s, e in zip(df2['start_date'], df2['end_date']) for x in pd.date_range(s, e)]

df1['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['date'])
df = df1[df1['date'].isin(L)]
print (df)
        date   x     
0 2021-01-20  10  ...
1 2021-01-22  20  ...
4 2021-03-25   4  ...
5 2021-03-27   4  ...
```

Comment: this doesn't seem to work in my code but thank you!

Comment: @JaniceWong - tested with change datetimes `2021-12-30` to `2020-12-30` and your data working in question for me.